# What is the smallest building block of ReactJS - Elements or Components?

Tags: reactjs

In React JS [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html), 
it is mentioned Elements are the smallest building blocks of ReactJS.

But, Components are also built, in order to create Elements. 
For example,

```
const element = <Welcome name="Sara" title="Mara"/>;

function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}

const element = <Welcome name="Sara" />;
ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

So, Component (here Welcome function component) was smallest building block that helped create an Element. 
So, Does it mean Components are the smallest building blocks? It is confusing. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

A react component is made up of simple html elements. But a react component's smallest element is the react component itself. 
A react component is actually an object with fields {type:..., state:..., props:...., children:....,} Where children will be componsed of other subtree objects(react elements). This object is used for calculating the difference in dom when a component is rerendered(on change of state or props) and pushing the objects with change and ignoring those which doesnt change.

Answer (score 0):

**React** is all about components. When you have complex **DOM** ( DOM is made up of elements ) it's React's way to break that complex DOM into granular smaller components.

The more granular it is, you are doing it the more **React** way (It's a React best practice).

coming to "**Components are the smallest build blocks ?**", well we can't say it that way, we can say "**React is all about components**"

It depends on us that how well we create granular components, which makes it easily reusable and maintainable.

Creating granular components always doesn't mean creating components with just one element.

**Granular Component ?**

```
import React from 'react';

const welcome = (props) => (
    <div>
        <p>props.welcomeMessage</p>

        <h3>Disclaimer</h3>
        <p>props.disclaimerMessage</p>
    </div>
);

export default welcome;
```

I can call this a granular component but we can also debate on the Disclaimer part of this code, Disclaimer also can be used elsewhere so it's always a good practice to identify such pieces and move them into there own components so that we get the complete benefits of **React**

We cannot call a component the smallest building block but yes we can break the HTML into proper, well-structured **Component Tree** to get the smallest ones.

Answer (score 0):

*Elements* and *Components* are different things in React, and the documentation you read explains the first of those, the *element*.

**Elements**:

> Elements are plain JavaScript objects that describe how your UI should be rendered.

If you are using JSX, describing *elements* looks quite similar to writing HTML.

```
// The `<div />` is JSX for creating a React *Element*
const element = <div>Foo</div>;
```

**Components**:

*Components* are separate from *elements*. As mentioned in the [Components and Props doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html), components are "like JavaScript functions" and "return React elements describing what should appear on the screen."

> React Components return React Elements describing what should appear on the screen

```
// This is a React *Component*: a Function that returns a React *Element*.
function MyComponent() {
  return <div>Foo</div>;
}

// You can also implement a React *Component* by extending `React.Component`
// and implementing a `render` method.
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Foo</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand that Components are different from Elements. But among these two, which is in the least position of hierarchy?

Comment: Components return Elements, so Elements are smallest/lowest in the hierarchy.